# get the number of instances of an element in a guava multiset without iterating

Tags: java, guava, multiset

I have a multiset in guava and I would like  to retrieve the number of instances of a given element without iterating over this multiset (I don't want to iterate because I assume that iterating takes quite some time, as it looks through all the collection).

To do that, I was thinking first to use the entryset() method of multiset, to obtain a set with single instances and their corresponding count. Then, transform this set into a hashmap (where keys are the elements of my set, and values are their instance count). Because then I can use the methods of hashmap to directly retrieve a value from its key - done! But this makes sense only if I can transform the set into the hashmap in a quick way (without iterating trhough all elements): is it possible?

(as I said I expect this question to be flawed on multiple counts, I'd be happy if you could shed light on the conceptual mistakes I probably make here. Thx!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may know in Guava `Multiset` is an interface, not a class.

If you just want to know the repeated number of an element, call `Multiset.count(Object element)`.

Please forget my following statement:

*Then if you are using a popular implementation `HashMultiset`, there is already a `HashMap<E, AtomicInteger>` working under the scene.
That is, when the `HashMultiset` iterates, also a HashMap iterates. No need to transform  into another HashMap.*

Comment: The first sentence is a red herring. The `Multiset` _interface_ specifies a `count` method (which is the correct one to use). No need to use `HashMultiset.count` specifically.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: Yes, `HashMultiset.count` overrides `Multiset.count`.

Comment: Sure. But that doesn't change the fact that you should still just use the `Multiset` interface, rather than `HashMultiset` explicitly. (i.e., `Multiset multiset = HashMultiset.create();`, not `HashMultiset multiset = HashMultiset.create();`.) You would still operate in terms of the `Multiset` interface; only the factory method needs to care that it's a `HashMultiset` behind the scenes.

Comment: Yeah, this answer is so strangely explained I posted a new answer just to, you know, give the answer, directly.

Comment: @Kevin Bourrillion: I edited my answer to reduce the confuse. Thank you author:)

Answer (score 8):

Simply invoke [`count(element)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html#count%28java.lang.Object%29) on your multiset -- voila!